# Embed JPG data properly in PDF files generated by Inkscape

Tags: pdf, jpeg, inkscape

There is a [bug in Inkscape](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/168708) where JPEG images included in an SVG document are embedded as bitmaps rather than JPEG when exporting to PDF files.

The result is a huge increase in file size.  For example, I have a simple SVG drawing which includes a 2 MB JPEG image; exporting to PDF results in a 14 MB file.

I am looking for a workaround.  Is there a way to **fix the resulting PDF** by inserting the correctly-encoded JPG image, perhaps via some sort of pdftk trickery?

(In my case, the resulting PDF will be included as a figure in a LaTeX document rendered with pdflatex, so there may be workarounds other than directly fixing the PDF generated by Inkscape.)

Comment: Finally fixed in Inkscape 0.91.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One kludge is to use `pdf2ps` followed by `ps2pdf`, which will re-encode the bitmap data as JPEG:

```
pdf2ps made-by-inkscape.pdf foo.ps
ps2pdf foo.ps smaller-file.pdf
```

For my test case, the file sizes were:

```
original JPEG           2.1M
made-by-inkscape.pdf   15M
foo.ps                104M
smaller-file.pdf        1.5M
```

But of course, this involves re-encoding the JPEG data, which is best avoided.

Comment: Note that ps2pdf can take pdf as input, you don't need to first produce a ps file.

Answer (score 1):

I found that with Inkscape 0.48.1 exporting to EPS instead, and passing the resulting EPS file to the [epstopdf script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf), produces good results. PNG/JPG files stay PNG/JPG within the PDF file, fonts look alright, etc.

Comment: This did not work well for me on Inkscape 0.48.4 (stock in Ubuntu 14.04). Created a quasi-trivial SVG with a 305604-byte JPEG. Export to PDF yields 2414085 bytes, `pdfimages -j` extracts a 2904016-byte PPM. Export to EPS yields 28295129 bytes. epstopdf (In Ubuntu package texlive-font-utils) produces 1223973 bytes PDF. `pdfimages -j` extracts a 821634-byte JPEG. Conclusion: it's been reencoded.